# fibers install not possible on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, node-fibers

When I try to install fibers, I get this errormessage.

I have Node version 0.10.45 for the use Meteor 1.3.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 64 Bits on a Strato VPS.

When I do a `meteor build` I need to run `npm install fibers` inside of `programs/server` of the build output. But I have no chance installing fibers as I get this output. I have not found anything yet about that problem on the web.

```
sudo npm install -g fibers

> fibers@1.0.13 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js
(...)    
make: Entering directory `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/fibers/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o
g++: internal compiler error: Bus error (program as)
(...)
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o] Error 4
make: Leaving directory `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/fibers/build'
(...)
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-042stab111.12
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/fibers
(...)
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++`
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-042stab111.12
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "fibers"
npm ERR! node v0.10.45
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! fibers@1.0.13 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.13 install script 'node build.js || nodejs build.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the fibers package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build.js || nodejs build.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs fibers
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/keller/repos/rmt-app/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the apt-get command in the middle of the output?

```
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++`
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
```

I ran into the same failure on Alpine, and running that command to install the necessary dependencies fixed it for me.